# Javascript redirect or reload

Tags: javascript

I have an ajax method which submits data over ajax. The server then responds with a URL to load. Most times the URL will be different to the one on which the request was made, but sometimes the URL is the same.

Either way, I want the page to go to the intended url, even it's just reloading the page.

I've tried the `window.location.href = ''` method, but if the current url is the same as the intended url, nothing happens.

I've tried the `window.location.replace(url)` method, but that doesn't reload the page if current === intended.

I've tried the `window.location.reload(true)` method, but that's only good if the current url is the same as the intended url.

I've tried to compare the intended URL to the current url and do either a reload or a `href` method, but this has problems as well. If I click on a bootstrap tab, the hash doesn't appear in the URL, so the `current url` value is actually incorrect.

For your reference, this is/was my comparison:

```
if(window.location.href === response.intended) {
    window.location.reload(true);
} else {
    window.location.replace(response.intended);
}
```

All I want to do, is force the browser to redirect to an intended URL, or reload the current page depending on current URL vs intended URL.

Comment: **I've tried the window.location.href = '' method, but if the current url is the same as the intended url, nothing happens.** Are you sure ?

Comment: is there any `#` character in the url?

Comment: @rajuGT sometimes there will be, i'm using bootstrap tabs.

Comment: Try this with current SO question URL. with `#` the page is just moving to the post. but if you remove that `#`, its reloading the whole page. Try and check the difference. This might be the issue I guess.

Comment: @RayonDabre At the moment, it's definately not doing it when there's a hash in the url (for bootstrap tabs), for example, `window.location.href = someurl.com/test.php#tab_1` doesn't reload / redirect the page.

Comment: @rajuGT is right. You may substring the text before '#' (if exists) and then compare the texts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To ensure your page isn't being cached, add a random number to the end of the url:

```
window.location.replace(response.intended + "?rnd" + Math.random() );
```

Comment: Good idea, didn't think of this approach! Thanks for an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Add `window.location.hash` to the new url for comparison. If there isn't one it will return an empty string

```
if(window.location.href === response.intended + window.location.hash) {
```

Answer (score 0):

As discussed over comments, I think this is due to the `#` character in the  url, which makes the browser to move to particular section of the page like `<a href='33347913'>` tag.

```
var index = response.intended.indexOf('#');
if(index >= 0) {
    response.intended = response.intended.substr(0, index);
}
window.location.href = response.intended;
```